# How to supplement the functionality of an Origen command?

Tags: origen-sdk

I looked at the Origen docs regarding [adding](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/commands/) and [overriding](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/commandsov/) commands and don't see any origen command besides -d that is forbidden from overriding.  However, when I try to override the target command, I do not see Origen doing the same things as it would when I execute the command.  Here is what i expect when I set a target:

```
peologin02:ppekit $ origen t mytarget.rb
Target now set to: mytarget.rb
```

When I do the same with my overidden command, the target does not change.  Here is my overridden target command:

```
when /target|^t$/
  unless ARGV.empty?
    curr_target = Origen.target.name
    new_target = ARGV.first
    unless curr_target == new_target
      # Remove the old target product's symlinks
      rm_src_links
    end
  end
  exit 0
```

I thought the 'exit  0' code would ensure that ARGV gets returned back to Origen for completing the target command, but it seems like nothing is done.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a command is dispatched, the current application gets the first crack at trying to handle it, followed by its plugins and then finally Origen core.

If at any time along the way the process is exited, then that will end the Origen command execution completely and those further down the priority chain will never even see the command.

Therefore, if you want to override the command completely so that the Original implementation is never hit, then call `exit 0` after you have handled it.

If you just want to supplement the existing behavior then don't call exit and the execution will continue on to the next in line.

In other words, remove `exit 0` in the example above and it should do what you want.